# Bit manipulation with Erlang's bitwise bnot operator

Tags: erlang, bit-manipulation

Reading [chapter 2](http://www.hackersdelight.org/basics2.pdf) of Hacker's Delight and trying ti implement bit manipulation in Erlang.

I'm stuck on this one:

> Use the following formula to create a word with 0's at the positions of the trailing 1's in x, and 1's elsewhere, producing all 1's if none (e.g. 10100111 => 11111000):
>
> ```
>           ¬ x | (x + 1)
> ```

Here is what I tried:

```
(bnot X) bor (X + 2#01)
```

But the result is `-1000` for some reason, and not `2#11111000`.

What's strange is that `not 2#10100111` is `-10101000` (base 2).

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: -1000 can be the same thing as 2#11111000, depending on how I read it. Can you confirm that it is indeed different?

Comment: Erlang doesn't limit the size of integers, so there is no fixed position for a sign bit. Just like positive numbers have an infinite prefix of zeros, negative numbers are seen as having an infinite prefix of ones. So, bnot 2#0001 is 2#...1110 (-2, in twos complement), bnot 2#0010 is 2#...1101 (-3 in twos complement), etc. By masking (band) with 2 bsl (W-1) - 1, you can truncate the result back to a positive number with W bits.

Comment: @RichardC Could you turn this into an answer? Did you mean that `2#...1101` is `-4`? Since `101` is 4? Or maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: The answer by @pascal below is correct, I just tried to clarify what's going on. E.g. 2#101 is 5 (not 4), but in twos complement, -5 is 11111011 (invert the positive number and add 1) if limited to 8 bits. In Erlang, you have to imagine an infinite number of ones to the left whenever you have a negative integer. If you mask this with "band 2#11111111" you'll keep only the low 8 bits, which will be a positive number in Erlang.

Answer (score 5):

You have to limit the width oh the numbers manipulated (problem of sign, problem of bignum and integer representation).

*The next example use 8 bits but it would work the same with 128 bits, in this case the result would be `340282366920938463463374607431768211448` instead of `248` for your test case.*

```
1> Msk = fun(X) -> X band 2#11111111 end. % limit to 8 bits
#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>
2> Op = fun(X) -> Msk(bnot(X)) bor Msk(X+1) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>
3> Op(2#10100111).
248
4> 2#11111000.
248
```